# How to connect to server, listen for arbitrary time and send back data

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm trying to:

1. Connect to a server/port
2. Listen for x seconds
3. Receive user input
4. Send user input to server
5. Go back to step 2

So far, I've written the following code, but it's not working properly receiving input after the first send. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import socket
import select

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('domain.com', 1234))
client_socket.setblocking(0)

timeout = 5
while True:
    while True:
        ready = select.select([client_socket], [], [], timeout)

        if ready[0]:
            data = client_socket.recv(4096)
            print data
        else:
            break

    data = raw_input("Enter input:")
    client_socket.send(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have separate server side code and client side code. [This](https://pymotw.com/2/select/) article has been referred.

**Server** binds to a port and listens for clients

server.py

```
import select
import socket

# Create a TCP/IP socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 1234)
server.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
server.listen(5)

# Sockets from which we expect to read
inputs = [ server ]

# Sockets to which we expect to write
outputs = [ ]

while inputs:

    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
    # Handle inputs
    for s in readable:

        if s is server:

            # A "readable" server socket is ready to accept a connection
            connection, client_address = s.accept()
            connection.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(connection)

        else:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print "Receiving data from client"
                print data
            else:
                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
```

**Client** first establishes a connection with the server and then keeps on sending user input to the server.

client.py

```
import socket

server_address = ('domain.com', 1234)

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.connect(server_address)

while True:

    data = raw_input("Enter input:")
    sock.send(data)
```

Open terminal.

Run server in background:

```
python server.py &
```

Run client after that:

```
python client.py
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but this project is for a client only. It will be connecting to arbitrary services, like netcat or telnet. I am looking to implement a proper "client loop". Thanks!

Comment: Why are you having 'select' in client code? The client is connecting to only one server..

Comment: select module seemed like the best way to loop recv through a socket based on an arbitrary amount of "listening time". If there's another, better way to accomplish this, I'm totally open!